# Excel 2016 opening last saved sheet instead of specific via hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I currently have a spreadsheet call it master.xls thats contains hyperlinks to worksheets in other spreadsheets for example worksheet called 'LHA' in spreadsheet child23.xls

Now, say I click hyperlink in A2 cell in master.xls for this sheet. It should open child23.xls and worksheet 'LHA'. But, instead it opens the last saved worksheet in child23.xls.

Hyperlink example:

child23.xls#'LHA'!A1

I have tried office repair but weirdly cannot fix this issue. Would anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: How are the hyperlinks created? See [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4439-excel-hyperlink-to-another-workbook-and-specific-worksheet-cell.html).

Comment: You can provide a screenshot about the hyperlink in Sheet.

Comment: Harrymc - via right click and insert link.

Comment: Lee - will do now